# Import data from Google Spreadsheets into MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, google-sheets

To do our annual stock counting, we have been using Google Spreadsheets, in a small company. As I am building an inventory management system, I am wondering what the best-practices are, when importing the data to MySQL.

The spreadsheets have the following structure:

```
PartNo. | Vendor | Title     | Quantity | Cost | Sum | EAN           | Comment | Price
841750  | Volvo  | Oil filter| 5        |   10 |  50 | 1234567812345 |         |    18
20.1418 | MarinH | Light     | 1        |   44 |  44 | 1234567812346 |         |    80
```

Google offers me the opinion to export to csv files, which mysql can read, but is there some *smarter* method?

You're also welcome to suggest me a database table structure :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out:

[how to import excel spreadsheet as table into mysql](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/770290.html)

> Navicat has a "table import wizard"
>   functionality. It's a free download
>   from
>   http://www.navicat.com/download.html
>   and it will import Excel spreadsheets
>   and create a new table in MySQL.

Using the above approach you could export your Google spreadsheet as an Excel .xls file and then use Navicat to import it to MySQL.

The option you described through a CSV file is also really good! I'd try that first. There are great tutorials on the internet showing you how to import a delimited .csv into a MySQL table.

Answer (score 0):

You can adhere to these methods to import data from a Google Spreadsheet into MySQL:

1. Create a CSV file by exporting your Google Spreadsheet. Click File > Download > Comma-separated values to accomplish this (.csv, current sheet).
2. Make that the CSV file is formatted appropriately by opening it in a text editor. A comma should be used to separate each column, and a new line should be created for each row.
3. For the data to be stored, make a new table in MySQL. You can accomplish this using a program like phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench.
4. Open the MySQL table and import the CSV file. To accomplish this, use the LOAD DATA INFILE command. Here is a command:

> ```
> LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/csv/file.csv' 
> INTO TABLE table_name 
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
> ENCLOSED BY '"' 
> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
> IGNORE 1 ROWS;
> ```

Replace /path/to/csv/file correctly. Change the other settings (such as the delimiter and line terminator) to match your CSV file by replacing csv with the actual path to your CSV file, table name with the name of the table you generated in step 3, and so on.

5. Run a query on the MySQL table to make sure the data was imported properly. You can accomplish this using the command line interface or a program like phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench.
   Remember that in order for MySQL to access the CSV file and import data into the table, you may need to establish permissions and other settings.

As an alternative - use the [Skyvia connector](https://skyvia.com/data-integration/integrate-google-sheets-mysql)